# How to disable snaps from starting at boot?

Tags: 18.04, snap, systemd

Snaps are awesome, but they cause slow boot time, especially if you have quite a few of them. `systemd-analyze blame` confirms this.

I tried to disable or even mask their main systemd services (`snapd.service` and `snapd.seeded.service`) but that doesn't do much; they have like a dozen `systemd` services, so I went down the rabbit hole with no success. Can anyone tell me how to disable them at boot time. I mean, is there a `systemd` service that controls all of them (I thought those two were, but apparently not)?

I want to run them in my own `systemd` service *after* the boot, so they can run without slowing down my boot time. How can I do this?

Version:  `2.42.5`

Comment: "`systemd-analyze blame` confirms this"  Be careful there. "blame" does not take into account that services wait for some other service. Snaps use fonts, If font caching is slow so are snaps. Problem then is not snaps but font caching. See as an example: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/03/the-cause-of-slow-snap-app-startup-times-has-been-identified  Question what version snap do you use? (edit it into the question please). And you will need to remove the snap packages and replace them with the "apt" versions to get rid of snap.

Comment: It definitely is a snap issue; I spent some time profiling it, and it becomes noticeable when the snap packages increase.. The link you cited relates to opening snap apps which is a bit different from my issue. My snap apps open just fine, I just want the `snapd` daemon not to slow down the boot time. 

I *do* use apt whenever possible but the packages I'm using snaps for either don't have apt counterparts or the apt versions aren't up-to-date. So "getting rid of them" isn't really a solution.